# Telegraf test input and output plugins error multiple conf files

Tags: testing, config, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-output-plugins

Telegraf version: **Telegraf v1.0.1**

I have the following files:

```
/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
```

main config file (which you create/get for free while installing telegraf). This file doesn't have any `[[output.<plugin>]]` stanza in it but does have valid default `inputs.xx` plugins enabled.

```
/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/1-company-output-plugin.conf
```

(This file has valid `outputs.<pluginname>` plugin).

```
/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/telegraf-additional-inputs-plugins.conf
```

(this file has additional `inputs.<pluginname>` plugins that I want to keep separate from the main conf file).

Running `sudo service telegraf status` shows Telegraf is running [OK]! and log file /var/log/telegrag/telegraf.log (looks good too without showing any errors).

If I make any changes to one of the above configuration files, I want to test those changes made (before I restart telegraf), so I'm running the following commands with `-test` or `--test` option but I'm getting the following error:

```
ubuntu@jenkins:~/test_aks_dir$ telegraf --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -test
2017/01/10 22:45:48 E! Error: no outputs found, did you provide a valid config file?
ubuntu@jenkins:~/test_aks_dir$ telegraf --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf --test
2017/01/10 22:45:51 E! Error: no outputs found, did you provide a valid config file?
```

As you see above, both optons `-test` or `--test` worked but also gave a **valid** error message above.

As the above error was for not providing any configuration stanza for `[[outputs.<plugin>]]`, I provided another --config file paramter for the file which contains the outputs plugin stanza, but now it gave an error for the missing inputs. file:

```
ubuntu@jenkins:~/test_aks_dir$ telegraf --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/1-company-output-plugin.conf  --test
2017/01/10 22:48:30 E! Error: no inputs found, did you provide a valid config file?
ubuntu@jenkins:~/test_aks_dir$
```

**Note:** The above command **didn't** error for providing multiple `--config <someConfigFile>` parameter values.

The same error comes if I want to test any change in the 3rd file : (*/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/telegraf-additional-inputs-plugins.conf*)

How can I test an **individual** or **selective** configuration file changes using `telegraf` **assuming I have multiple files** here: */etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/*.conf* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible at the moment, the only way to do it would be to specify the entire config directory

Comment: Yea, giving `--config-directory /etc/telegraf` works, which I tried already. Would be good if in future, we can just test a single config file otherwise, a user has to `grep` the lines all the time to see what's coming out from a plugin which may exist only in one config file (which is my case). If it's not supported at the moment, then I'm wondering why at command line, I was able to give more than one `--config cccccc` config files and it didn't error out (that makes one believe that telegraf cmd supports individual config files for `-test` or `--test`).

Comment: I guess `--input-filter=<plugin_name_in_your_extra_config_file>` will help to filter out (other than using `grep`) with `--test` and `--config-directory=/etc/telegraf` command line options. Ex: `telegraf --config-directory=/etc/telegraf --test --input-filter=filestat`